How to get pap authentication result in freeRADIUS?
In freeradius, in authenticate section of default virtual server, I have the following code
Auth-Type PAP {
   pap
   if (ok) {
      update reply {
         Reply-Message:="Access Accepted"
      }
   } else {
      update reply {
         Reply-Message := "Access Rejected"
      }
   }
}

raqdchekc table has the following records
nemo    Cleartext-Password  :=   arctangent
nemo    NAS-Port             ==  3

and I test it by radtest with different values as follows
radtest nemo arctangent 172.17.3.182 3 secretkey

1- I want to save reply-message(with different content) in a table, but when pap failed (on succes, it is ok), Reply-Message is not set and have empty value (however I can set it in Post-Auth-Type REJECT, but my question is why it doesn't set here).
2- How can I know mismathed item?

Could you post the debug output (radiusd -X || freeradius -X) when you run your test request.  That will let us know what the server is doing.
